# Select new object that contains a list of other objects in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object that contains lists of other objects.

```
public class MyNewClassWithEverything
{
    public MasterItem itemMaster { get; set; }
    public Item item { get; set; }
    public List<Itemfields> Itemsfields { get; set; }
    public List<ItemMasterfields> ItemMasterfields { get; set; }
}
```

In my Linq i have

```
var mainData = from uo in _context.UserOrgs
   join m in _context.MasterItem on uo.Organization equals m.Organization
   join i in _context.Item on m.Id equals i.MasterId
   join p in _context.ItemMasterfields on i.MasterId equals p.MasterId
   join z in _context.Itemfields on i.Id equals z.ItemId
   where uo.UserId == 6923 && m.DatePaid >= PaymentStartDate && m.DatePaid < PaymentEndDate
   select new MyNewClassWithEverything
   {
       Itemsfields = new List<Itemsfields> { z },
       ItemMasterfields = new List<ItemMasterfields> { p },
       ItemMaster = m,
       Items = i
   };
```

However when i run my app i am getting an exception

> The given expression 'new MyNewClassWithEverything()
>    does not contain the searched expression '[z]' in a nested
>    NewExpression with member assignments or a MemberBindingExpression

How should i be populating the new list?

Comment: Assuming that because of your use of `_context` that this refers to an Entity Framework `DbContext` class? If so, this complex query could be represented in your object model which would simplify things massively. Addressing your question directly, you will need to flatten our your results using `.SelectMany()` LINQ extension method (I'm not sure how to do this in query syntax), then leverage `.GroupBy()` to arrange the results.

Comment: What would that look like?

Comment: If I am reading this right, your code will **potentially** return multiple `MyNewClassWithEverything` objects. Is that what you are expecting?

Comment: No only one my new class with everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `_context.Itemfields.Where` get the collection in property instead of linq `join`.

```
var mainData = from uo in _context.UserOrgs
               join m in _context.MasterItem on uo.Organization equals m.Organization
               join i in _context.Item on m.Id equals i.MasterId
               where uo.UserId == 6923 && m.DatePaid >= PaymentStartDate && m.DatePaid < PaymentEndDate
               select new MyNewClassWithEverything
               {
                   Itemsfields = _context.Itemfields.Where(x=>x.ItemId == i.Id).toList(),
                   ItemMasterfields = _context.ItemMasterfields.Where(l=>l.MasterId == i.MasterId).toList(),
                   ItemMaster = m,
                   Items = i
               };
```

Comment: This works but it is really slow which is why i wanted to use the join.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `into` clause in your join to use the joined records as a group:

```
var mainData = from uo in _context.UserOrgs
   join m in _context.MasterItem on uo.Organization equals m.Organization
   join i in _context.Item on m.Id equals i.MasterId
   join p in _context.ItemMasterfields on i.MasterId equals p.MasterId
      into ps
   join z in _context.Itemfields on i.Id equals z.ItemId
      into zs
   where uo.UserId == 6923 && m.DatePaid >= PaymentStartDate && m.DatePaid < PaymentEndDate
   select new MyNewClassWithEverything
   {
       Itemsfields = zs.ToList(),
       ItemMasterfields = ps.ToList(),
       ItemMaster = m,
       Items = i
   };
```

If you get an error on `ToList`, you can either change your property types to `IEnumerable<T>` or call `AsEnuerable()` and do a second projection to turn the groups into list outside of the EF query.